# Amazon AppConfig from Spring Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-sdk, aws-app-config

How can I access configurations from aws appconfig, in my spring boot application?

Since appconfig is a new service, is there any java sdk that we can use, cos i dont see anything for appconfig yet in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples

Answer (score 2):

2023, use `aws-java-sdk-appconfigdata`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-appconfigdata</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.394</version>
</dependency>
```

example:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AWSAppConfig {

    private String token;
    private final AWSAppConfigData client;

    public AWSAppConfig() {
        log.info("init app config");
        var client = AWSAppConfigDataClient.builder().build();
        var request = new StartConfigurationSessionRequest();
        request.setEnvironmentIdentifier("prod");
        request.setApplicationIdentifier("my-app");
        request.setConfigurationProfileIdentifier("my-config");
        request.setRequiredMinimumPollIntervalInSeconds(15);
        var result = client.startConfigurationSession(request);
        this.client = client;
        this.token = result.getInitialConfigurationToken();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
    public void pollConfiguration() {
        var request = new GetLatestConfigurationRequest();
        request.setConfigurationToken(token);
        var result = client.getLatestConfiguration(request);
        this.token = result.getNextPollConfigurationToken();
        var configuration = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(result.getConfiguration()).toString();
        log.info("content type: {}", result.getContentType());
        log.info("configuration: {}", configuration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've integrated AWS AppConfig into my Spring Boot project.

First, let’s make sure we have this dependency in our pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-appconfig</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.134</version>
 </dependency>
```

Next, let’s create a simple configuration class of our own AWS AppConfig Client:

```
@Configuration
public class AwsAppConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AwsAppConfiguration.class);

    private final AmazonAppConfig appConfig;
    private final GetConfigurationRequest request;

    public AwsAppConfiguration() {
        appConfig = AmazonAppConfigClient.builder().build();
        request = new GetConfigurationRequest();
        request.setClientId("clientId");
        request.setApplication("FeatureProperties");
        request.setConfiguration("JsonProperties");
        request.setEnvironment("dev");
    }

    public JSONObject getConfiguration() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        GetConfigurationResult result = appConfig.getConfiguration(request);
        String message = String.format("contentType: %s", result.getContentType());
        LOGGER.info(message);

        if (!Objects.equals("application/json", result.getContentType())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("config is expected to be JSON");
        }

        String content = new String(result.getContent().array(), "ASCII");
        return new JSONObject(content).getJSONObject("feature");
    }
}
```

Lastly, let’s create a scheduled task that polls the configuration from AWS AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AwsAppConfigScheduledTask {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AwsAppConfigScheduledTask.class);

    @Autowired
    private FeatureProperties featureProperties;

    @Autowired
    private AwsAppConfiguration appConfiguration;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void pollConfiguration() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        LOGGER.info("polls configuration from aws app config");
        JSONObject externalizedConfig = appConfiguration.getConfiguration();
        featureProperties.setEnabled(externalizedConfig.getBoolean("enabled"));
        featureProperties.setLimit(externalizedConfig.getInt("limit"));
    }

}
```

I came across this question, as I was also trying to figure out how to best integrate AWS AppConfig into Spring Boot.

Here's an article I created. You can visit it here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/create-features-toggles-using-aws-appconfig-in-spring-boot-7454b122bf91

Also, the source code is available on github: https://github.com/emyasa/medium-articles/tree/master/aws-spring-boot/app-config

Comment: What if I do not want to write a scheduled JOB? How can AppConfig let my Spring app knows about the changes automatically?
One solution other than writing a scheduler is Spring Actuator where I can write the same code into /refresh the end-point.
Thanks.

Comment: @Hiren If there's a need to do it automatically, based on AWS Documentation — it's possible to configure AWS Config to stream configuration changes and notifications to an Amazon SNS topic. 

With that, perhaps we can send the message to an SQS — then consume it on the application end. I haven't yet tried that, though. Anyway, here's the link to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/notifications-for-AWS-Config.html

Answer (score 1):

First I added dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>appconfig</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.41</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/appconfigdata -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>appconfigdata</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then build the client

```
        client = AppConfigDataClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create("<your id>", "your secret key"))
            .region(Region.<your region>)
            .build();
```

Use the client to start the configuration session

```
        StartConfigurationSessionRequest startConfigurationSessionRequest = StartConfigurationSessionRequest.builder()
            .applicationIdentifier("<your application id>")
            .environmentIdentifier("your environment id")
            .configurationProfileIdentifier("your config id")
            .build();
```

Get the session token in the beginning and use it for the initial call.

```
String sessionToken = client.startConfigurationSession(startConfigurationSessionRequest).initialConfigurationToken();
    
    
    GetLatestConfigurationRequest latestConfigurationRequest = GetLatestConfigurationRequest.builder()
            .configurationToken(sessionToken)
            .build();
    GetLatestConfigurationResponse latestConfigurationResponse = client.getLatestConfiguration(latestConfigurationRequest);
    String response =  latestConfigurationResponse.configuration().asUtf8String();
```

You can use the next token available in the response to make the next call. The token can be cached as required.